# Two views in one

Tags: view, grouping

I have a view of a document library grouped using 2 different columns, but would like to display an additional grouping using 2 other columns, but in the same view.

example:

```
first you have the list displayed as
Assigned to: user1 -
    - Status: completed +
    - Status: In Progress +

Assigned to: User2 -
    - Status: completed +
    - Status: In Progress -
       - Item 1
       - Item 2
```

And then right below I would have for example

```
Status: Completed +

Status: In Progress -
 - Priority: High +
 - Priority: Low -
     - Item 1
     - Item 2
```

but rather than having 2 different views to display a different way of grouping I want it in the same view, for quick overview

I tried by adding a web part but I have no options to customize the additional list to group it like above

Answer (score -1):

Check this link:
http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.in/2011/01/sharepoint-group-by-on-more-than-2.html

You will require designer to do this.

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for. I'm looking for displaying esentially 2x 2-tier (not 3) grouping, but on the same page/in the same view.